# How to restrict validation for mandatory fields in javascript when they are hidden on a condition?

Tags: javascript

How to restrict validation for mandatory fields in javascript when few of them are hidden on a condition?

first name &last name fields visible in user profile page on one condition, and not visible on another condition. When they are not visible, then also javascript is validating these fields. How to restrict validation when they are not visible?

thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
function validateEditPage() {

    var fname = '<%=txtFName.ClientID %>';
    var lname = '<%=txtLName.ClientID %>';

    if (document.getElementById(fname) != null) {
        var varFirstName = document.getElementById(fname).value;
        if (varFirstName == "") {
            ShowErrorMessage('Please Enter First Name');
            document.getElementById(fname).value = "";
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (document.getElementById(lname) != null) {
        var varLName = document.getElementById(lname).value;
        if (varLName == "") {
            ShowErrorMessage('Please Enter Last Name');
            document.getElementById(lname).focus();
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First try to check if it's visible by :

```
 if(document.getElementById("textboxId").style.visibility != "hidden")
    {
         //validation code
    }
```

Comment: Hi..Rakesh, thanks for the response, its not working for me!

Comment: how are you hiding the textbox ? using css visibility:hidden or display:none ?